# Edit to the OP's question title

Tags: discussion

Is it considered rude or bad form to either comment on or edit an original poster's question title in order to fix a grammatical error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because basic research

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entire point of allowing anyone to edit posts is so that mistakes can be fixed. Because your edits will need to be approved by other users, make sure you fix as many problems with the post as you can. Try to leave as good an edit summary as possible, since edit summaries are public (the original poster is likely to see it, so don't be rude!).

Those are the very basics, so if there's anything else you want to know feel free to ask me!

For extremely in depth information see: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/323179)

Comment: Good link. Something else to keep in mind is that editing a post bumps it to the home page. A trivial edit to correct a typo in the title of a low-voted question from five years ago may not be worth elevating it to the home page. Some long-forgotten questions with a few minor errors are best left where they are.